# Rspec-rails-capybara js: true causing delay in Mailers resulting in test failures

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

```
describe 'salary acceptance email' do
  let!(:effective_date)  { Date.current.next_week }
  let(:salary) { FactoryGirl.create(:salary) } 

  it 'displays admin selected effective_date', js: true do

    page.visit approval_path(salary)
    page.uncheck('default_effective_date')
    select effective_date.year.to_s, from: 'offer_effective_date_date_1i'
    select I18n.t("date.month_names")[effective_date.month] , from: 'offer_effective_date_date_2i'
    select effective_date.day.to_s, from: 'offer_effective_date_date_3i'
    click_on 'Accept'
    #binding.pry or wait_for_ajax - hack to let the test pass

    expect(mail.body).to include_in_each_part(salary.amount)
    expect(mail.body).to include_in_each_part(effective_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  end
end
```

There isn't any ajax request in this part of the code except that there is a javascript which hides/displays the effective_date date_select tag.
When I add js: true to the spec mail[=>   ActionMailer::Base.deliveries
.last] returns nil but if the test is allowed to wait for a second or two things would work fine. How do I fix this without the HACK ! :(

Capybara Version :     capybara (1.1.3)

Webkit Version   :     capybara-webkit (0.13.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding a check for something on that page which changes after clicking accept

```
describe 'salary acceptance email' do
 let!(:effective_date)  { Date.current.next_week }
 let(:salary) { FactoryGirl.create(:salary) } 

 it 'displays admin selected effective_date', js: true do

  page.visit approval_path(salary)
  page.uncheck('default_effective_date')
  select effective_date.year.to_s, from: 'offer_effective_date_date_1i'
  select I18n.t("date.month_names")[effective_date.month] , from: 'offer_effective_date_date_2i'
  select effective_date.day.to_s, from: 'offer_effective_date_date_3i'
  click_on 'Accept'

  expect(page).to have_content("Acceptance Completed Successfully")
  expect(mail.body).to include_in_each_part(salary.amount)
  expect(mail.body).to include_in_each_part(effective_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
 end
end
```

All credits to capybara team :star: .Check out for more details in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/EpbORzw7rq8